# Библиотека для распознавания слова раз и раза в числе

Tags: javascript, angular

Я работаю в Angular и мне нужна библиотека, которая будет распознавать слова раз и раза в числе, т.е 1 раз, 2 раза и т.д. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такая библиотека на angular или на javaScript.

Comment: [google.com/search?q=angular+string+pipe](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+string+pipe) -> https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, такая библиотека и есть, но это несложная задача, поэтому умещается в небольшую пайпу.

```
/**
* @param value
* @type number
*
* @param wordforms
* @type string | string[]
*
* @description
* помимо числа, пайпе надо скормить 3 формы слова для следующих групп
*
* 1 - раз, человек, яицо, майка
* 2 - 4 - раза, человека, яйца, майки
* 0, 5 - 9 - раз, человек, яиц, маек
* 20 - 99 - повторение групп выше
* 10 - 19 - раз, человек, яиц, маек (особая группа не реагирующая на разряд единиц)
* 100+ оставляем за скобками разряд сотен и выше и повторяем словоформы из групп выше
*
* Итого надо предоставить три формы слова:
* раз - раза - раз
* человек - человека - человек
* яйцо - яйца - яиц
* майка - майки - маек
*/


@Pipe({
    name: 'wordformru'
})
export class WordFormRuPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value: number, wordforms: string | string[]): string {
        const output = ((v) => (form) => `${v} ${form}`)(value);

        if (typeof wordforms === 'string') {
            wordforms = wordforms.split(',');
        }
        const [single, twoFour, many] = wordforms;

        value %= 100; // забираем только остаток от деления на 100
        if (value >= 10 && value < 20) {
            return output(many);
        }

        value %= 10; // забираем только остаток от деления на 10
        if (value === 1) { return output(single); }
        else if (value === 0 || value > 4) { return output(many); }
        else { return output(twoFour); }
    }
}
```

Использование в темплейте выглядит достаточно просто

```
<p>{{ number | wordformru:'раз,раза,раз' }}</p>
```